# Function executes despite call to `render`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The objective of the app is to facilitate upload/download of files for users.

**If the user does not select any file and tries to click upload, a prompt needs to be displayed.**

```
def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment => {:file => [ :original_filename ]}])

        if params[:attachment].nil?
          flash[:alert] = "No file!"
          render "new"
        end

        uploaded_io = params[:attachment][:file]
        @attachment.user_id = @user.id
        @attachment.name = params[:attachment][:file].original_filename
        @attachment.format = params[:attachment][:file].content_type
        @attachment.save
        File.open(Rails.root.join('public/data', @attachment.name), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(uploaded_io.read)
        end

    redirect_to user_attachments_path, notice: "The file #{@attachment.name} has been uploaded."
end
```

Despite the `if params[:atttachment].nil?` block, I receive an error at the `uploaded_io = params[:attachment][:file]` statement.

`params[:attachment].nil?` returns `true` when no file is selected[checked using debugger]

Any reason why the if block is not executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return to be able to render, otherwise you'll get a double render error, try something like this

```
if params[:attachment].nil?
  flash[:alert] = "No file!"
  return render "new"
end
```

Also another notice, when you're rendering directly, the flash message won't appear, it appears in the following request, instead you need to tell rails that you want that flash message to appear right away, so instead of just using `flash`, use `flash.now`

```
if params[:attachment].nil?
  flash.now[:alert] = "No file!"
  return render "new"
end
```

Comment: So `render` and `redirect_to` do not return. Is that something deliberately put in because they appear like functions that should definitely return and anything after the call should not be executed (at least how that appears to me)

Comment: Usually we put `render` and `redirect` calls in the last statement in the method (action), and since ruby by default returns the last statement, you don't feel that you need to return it, but yea both should always be returned, the `return` keyword though is not needed most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

**you just have an if loop ,so irrespective of whether you code goes in if loop or  not,you are executing every code outside of if loop,which you needed to handle using if else.That means,code after if loop will always get executed,which should not be the case if its dependent of `params[:attachment]`**
**i have updated your code by using proper if else loop ..try to use this ...**

```
            def create
                @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
                @attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment => {:file => [ :original_filename ]}])
                ##you can use .blank?  as well
                if params[:attachment].nil?
                  flash[:alert] = "No file!"
                  render "new"
                else    
                 uploaded_io = params[:attachment][:file]
                 @attachment.user_id = @user.id
                 @attachment.name = params[:attachment][:file].original_filename
                 @attachment.format = params[:attachment][:file].content_type
                 @attachment.save
                 File.open(Rails.root.join('public/data', @attachment.name), 'wb') do |file|
                 file.write(uploaded_io.read)
                 end
                 redirect_to user_attachments_path, notice: "The file #{@attachment.name} has been uploaded."
               end
            end
```

Comment: I get what you have done there. This is what I ended up doing, but I would appreciate if you would rather explain what I was missing out rather than give me the answer. Thank you for the correct answer thouogh :)

Comment: @Sinstein...i have updated my answer with some more comments..hope this might help you understand.....